# How to change ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

I'm trying to do an Angular JS app but I'va some questions.

This is my index.html code

```
<body ng-app="StockApp">
        <div id="wrapper" class="flex-column">
            <div ng-hide="hideNavBar" id="navbarundsub">
            </div>
            <div ng-show="hideStockInformation" id="stockInformation">
            </div>
            <div id="main" class="flex-row">
                <div ng-hide="hideSideMenu" id="sidemenu">
                </div>
                <div ng-hide="hideSideMenuUser" id="sidemenuUser">
                </div>
                <!--CONTENIDO-->
                <ng-view></ng-view>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

My question is that my first page is a login so I don't want to show the login.html inside the divs where de ng-view is, so I don't know how can I change the ng-view or how can I pass grom the login to the other page... I don't know.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: refer https://thinkster.io/ng-view and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm for more understanding

Answer (score 1):

ng-view is one of the important directives of Angular1.

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

We need to inject ngRoute in dependancy injection.
Here we need to maintain routes like this

[Routing Example](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing)

Please maintain routes like this

```
     var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);
     mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.

        when('/login', {
           templateUrl: 'login.htm',
           controller: 'LoginController'
        }).

        when('/employee', {
           templateUrl: 'employee.htm',
           controller: 'EmployeeController'
        }).

        otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/login'
        });
     }]);
```

Comment: I already did that. My problem is that loging is an indepent page and I don't want to show it with ng-view

Comment: The problem with ng-show is that it doesn't respect the design

Comment: Better use ng-include @Enya

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 angular template one for login and another for dashboard.

login template not contains any menu and header where
dashboard template contains both menu and header.

you have to change your route from one template page to another template page.
for that you need to use ui-router angular module.using ng-route you can't change route from one template page to another template page.

ui-router module:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

**app.js**

```
angular
  .module('myapp', [
    'ui.router',
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard/Home');
      $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
          url: '/dashboard',
          templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/main.html', 
        })
        .state('home', {
          parent:'dashboard',
          url: '/Home',
          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'views/pages/blank.html',

          }
        })
        .state('login', {
          templateUrl: 'views/pages/login.html',
          url: '/login'
        })
    }
  ]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">


        <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/libs/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/sb-admin-2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/timeline.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/libs/metisMenu.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/libs/loading-bar.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/libs/font-awesome.min.css" 
        type="text/css">
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- bower:js -->
        <script src="js/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <!-- endbower -->


        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="ApsilonApp">
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```